# Typescript alias import with auto-complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

===== 2021/03/17 Update =====

If anyone still have the same issue. You can try this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ...

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/components'),
    },
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  ...

  "baseUrl": ".",
  "path": {
    "components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
  }
}
```

===== Origin Post =====

I have a Alert React component below:

```
  import React from 'react';
  
  interface Props {
    message: string;
  };

  const Alert = (props: Props) => {
    return (
      <div>{props.message}</div>
    );
  };

  export default Alert;
```

I use the **alias import** instead of **relative import**:

```
  // alias import
  import Alert from 'components/Alert';

  // relative import
  // import Alert from '../../components/Alert';  

  const App = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Alert message="I want to know the interface of Alert" />
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default App;
```

If I type "<Alert me" in **relative import**, VSCode will show the auto-complete options.

However, when I use the **alias import**, VSCode won't show the auto-complete.

Is there any possible way to let the VSCode knows the 'components/Alert' is '../../components/Alert', and show me the auto-complete that I can understand the interface of Alert's props?

Here is how I setting the alias, I had been tried both **webpack config** and **tsconfig**:

**webpack.config.js**

```
  ...

  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
    alias: {
      'components/*': path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/components/*'),
      'containers/*': path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/containers/*'),
      'images/*': path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/images/*'),
      'hooks/*': path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/hooks/*'),
    },
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "components": ["components"],
      "containers": ["containers"],
      "images": ["images"],
      "hooks": ["hooks"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

folder structure:

```
  - src
    - components
      - Alert
        - index.tsx
    - containers
      - App
        - index.tsx
```

Comment: Provide the way you setting the "alias"

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json code ? Do you have a `paths` property in there ?

Comment: @hoangdv I updated the code about setting alias, thanks!

Comment: @klugjo I updated the code about tsconfig.json, thanks!

Comment: It looks like the one of the correct path in your `tsconfig.json` should be: `paths: { "components/*": ["./components/*"] }`

Comment: @tmhao2005 I tried your solution, but it's not working... is it possible to call out the auto-complete using without relative import ?

Comment: In my case it's working normally. I'm not sure if there is mystery which I don't know in your project. BTW in terms of making this work with VS code, you might have just only change the `tsconfig.json`. Or let's try to restart your VS code is also not a bad idea :)

Comment: @tmhao2005 I tried to restart the VSCode... and it's work! very awesome! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the `baseUrl` option as relative to the paths you are aliasing, so if you have alias path set to `./src/components` then the `baseUrl` of that path is `./`.

Here is an example:

```
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "./src/components/*"
      ],
```

or

```
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
```